# How to use CONCAT with + in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, concatenation

I tried using CONCAT with + sign in SQL, however I am not getting the correct syntax to perform this query. The tool that I am using is Google BigQuery.

Answer (score 8):

To concatenate strings in BigQuery, we can either use the [`CONCAT()`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#concat) function, or we can use the `||` ANSI concatenation operator:

```sql
SELECT CONCAT('Hello', 'World')
SELECT 'Hello' || 'World'
```

Other databases such as SQL Server use the `+` operator for string concatenation, but not BigQuery.

Comment: We've been using the `CONCAT` function at work for years. I wonder if there's any difference between these two methods apart from which syntax is preferred. When I think about it, the only thing I can come up with would be that using `||` means you can concatenate strings with a cleaner syntax if you have more than two strings to concatenate. Ex. `CONCAT('A', CONCAT('B', 'C'))` vs. `'A' || 'B' || 'C'`. The latter is probably considered easier to read than the former by basically everyone.

Comment: `CONCAT` accepts one or more arguments so you would do `CONCAT('A', 'B', 'C')` https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#concat

Answer (score 1):

One more option :o)

```
SELECT FORMAT('%s %s', 'Hello', 'World')
```

Comment: I've seen some assertions that format functions like these can have poor performance in some programming languages. Do you know if, for the purpose of concatenating strings, this is less performant in BigQuery compared to using `CONCAT` (nested if you have more than two strings to concatenate) vs. a single call to `FORMAT`? Then again, performance of this operation probably doesn't matter much, because BigQuery users would be more likely to encounter performance problems related to inefficiently joining data, or not filtering out enough with `WHERE`, etc, not processing strings.

Comment: [format function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#format_string) is most flexible as you can do many formatting tricks beyond just simple concatenation. and obviously this comes with overhead